# Caching a frequently used queryset in django

Tags: django, caching

I have a model which is being used a lot in my app (and the data in it almost never changes, unless a dev wants to change something).
I'd like to cache this queryset to see what difference it will make for the speed of my views, but can't really get my head around it.

I'm using redis and i set the cache like this:

```
m = MyModel.objects.all()
cache.set('m', m, timeout=None)
```

And then I get it like this:

```
c = cache.get('m')
for x in range(1,200):
    o = c.get(pk=x)
```

... which of course leads to 200 DB queries.

How can I store everything in the cache so that every lookup I do gets the data from the cache? Should I set each individual entry in the cache such as `cache.set(primary_key, object)`? Or should I convert it to a dictionary or something?

Answer (score 0):

Can pickle the queryset and then store it in cache, which then takes everything from cache itself